# Is it possible to witness forgiveness by Allah?

Tags: allah, forgiveness

Allah is noted for his ability to forgive.

[image: Qur'an 3:135 And who forgives sins except Allah]

(Image source: http://themuslimahnetwork.com/)

The longer version of [Qur'an 3:135](http://islamawakened.com/quran/3/135/):

> And those who, having done an act of indecency to be ashamed of, or wronged their own souls, remember Allah, and ask for forgiveness for their sins,- and who can forgive sins except Allah? - and are never obstinate in persisting knowingly in (the wrong) they have done.

**Question**: Is it possible to witness forgiveness by Allah?

Even if forgiveness were immediate, I wouldn't even know what to look for.  How would I even recognize forgiveness?

Comment: Here's a good source: https://www.al-islam.org/self-building-ayatullah-ibrahim-amini/repentance-and-self-cleansing